# How to pass an image from an UIImageView to another ViewController's ImageView?

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview

I'm new to iOS development and I didn't find a working solution to my problem.

My application allows user to take a picture from camera or camera roll and then displays this picture in a `UIImageView` in `viewcontroller1`.

I would like this image to be sent to another `UIImageView` in `viewcontroller2` when clicking on a button on the `viewcontroller1`.

I am using Storyboard and the latest version of Xcode (target : iOS 6).

I've already tried `NSUserDefaults` method without success. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you present the next View Controller, in the `prepareForSegue:` method you write:

```
SecondVC *secondVC = segue.destinationViewController;
secondVC.imageView.image = self.imageView.image;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Levi, thank you for the answer. I'm not familiar with the prepareForSegue method. I didn't implement it. Where do I put it? In the first or secondview controller?

Comment: In the first. It is called automatically, when a segue is triggered. It allows you to pass data to the second View Controller. You can read about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: The doc is very short here. Would you mind to show me a bit of code with the IBAction and the prepareForSegue for VC1 and the code to implement in VC2? I'm a bit lost I'm afraid. I bet this is easy, but I'm getting more and more frustrated by not understanding how it works. Cheers.